# Excel / VBA how to remove weekend days from a value

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a production worksheet. This worksheet contains a column of cells with the operational lead time (time that a product has been in x department). Only the value of this cell is not correct with the actual time that "could have been" spent on working on the product. This is due to the fact that weekend days are also counted (note the cells in this column do not contain a formula that counts, just a value that was dumped from a database).

To illustrate lets say the value of the cell is currently 13, which means the product arrived at said department 13 days ago. However this includes weekend days (production is halted in weekends) since today is thursday, 4 weekend days would need to be subtracted to get the actual operational leadtime.

Now here is my question, is it possible to automate that over a large column of values using excel in some way (formula's or VBA) to deduct weekend days based on the current date counting backwards?

Comment: There's a [built-in function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7) for calculating the [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(economics)) Workdays between two dates.

Comment: Thanks @Chronocidal that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Also, mod(date,7) is a simple way to get day of week, and mod(date,7)<2 is TRUE if date is a Saturday  or Sunday.